# Remove numbers from a specific place in a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
/abcd1/ef/gh001/d
```

Read the above line in to a string (String test)

I want to remove number after `abcd`

The required output is `/abcd/ef/gh001/d`

I have used the following code

```
test = Regex.Replace(test, "[0-9]", "");
```

but it removes all the numbers from the line like this

```
/abcd/ef/gh/d
```

Please help!!

Comment: Does the number you want to remove consistently come after something like "abcd" or do you not know?

Answer (score 3):

Since you *know* where the digits are, you could make a small adjustment to your expression such that it becomes: `test = Regex.Replace(test, "(abcd)[0-9]+", "$1");`.

This expression will match `abcd1` and place `abcd` within a group. This group is then accessed later through `$1`, so basically you would be replacing `abcd1` with `abcd`.

An alternative would be `test = Regex.Replace(test, "abcd[0-9]+", "abcd");`, which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*positive lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that you are replacing only the numbers that immediately follow `abcd`:

```
test = Regex.Replace(test, @"(?<=abcd)\d+", "");
```

In the example above, one or more digits `\d+` will be matched only if they immediately follow `abcd` string.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/iq3xPE)

Answer (score 0):

In my my case, the text abcd is not constant - the text could be anything

```
example1     /abcd1/ef/gh001/d
example2     /tmcy1/ef/gh001/d
```

but the location of the string  constant. It always comes at the first between //

```
/**abcd1**/ef/gh001/d
```

Comment: Is this the answer, or an addendum to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex replacement:

```
(?i)^(/[a-z]+)\d+(.*)
```

And replace with `$1$2`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fi)%5E(%2F%5Ba-z%5D%2B)%5Cd%2B(.*)&i=%2Fabcd1%2Fef%2Fgh001%2Fd&r=%241%242)